# Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '_?'

Tags: swift, generics

So I'm struggling with Swift generics. I'm trying to create an instance of a struct that is defined in a different module. The struct has a generic type for it's property.

Module code:

```
public struct MyModuleResponse<T> {
    let payload: T?
}
```

Main target code:

```
@import MyModule
....
let payload = "Something"
let result = MyModuleResponse(payload: payload)
```

This results in the error:

> Cannot convert the value of type 'String' to expected argument type '_?'

If I declare an indentical version of the struct in the main target:

```
public struct MyOwnResponse<T> {
    let payload: T?
}

let payload = "Something"
let result = MyOwnResponse(payload: payload)
```

No error and builds as expected.

My setup:

- Xcode 10.0
- Swift 4.2

Example project can be found here: https://github.com/cameroncooke/generics

Any one that can help me understand what is going on here would be really apreciated.

Also would be useful to know what Swift means by `type _`, what does `_` represent. The error message is very ambigous and doesn't really give any clues.

Comment: The `_` is the wildcard pattern, it means _discard whatever the `_` was substituted in for_. In this case, it means `Optional<_>` or in other words the compiler was expecting an `Optional` with any specialised value, but got a `String` instead. This behaviour seems like a bug to me, but just out of curiosity: what happens if you type annotate `payload` as `let payload: String?` or type annotate `result` as `let result:MyModuleResponse<String>`?

Comment: If I type annotate `result` I get the same error, if I remove the generic type from `MyModuleResponse` interestingly I get `'MyModuleResponse' initializer is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level`. I assume because the memberwise initializer is always defined `internal`.

Comment: Then it seems the real error was indeed due to the member wise initialiser's access level defaulting to `internal` and the other error was caused by the compiler not being able to infer the generic type due to the fact that it couldn't access the initialiser.

Comment: Now that makes a lot of sense, not very helpful the Swift compiler sometimes, spent ages on the type issue when it was in-fact an access control issue.

Comment: Yes, that seems like a bug to me, so feel free to create a bug report at https://bugs.swift.org

Comment: Done ;-) https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8959

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Dávid said `payload` variable must me Optional.

Swift initializer default protection level is `internal`. You need to set protection level for MyModuleResponse initializer to `public`.

```
public init(payload: T?) {
    self.payload = payload
}
```

Comment: That works! So the `Cannot convert the value of type 'String' to expected argument type '_?'` is a red-herring?, fixing the initialiser access level fixed the problem without needing to type annotate `payload` as Optional.

Comment: Yes, it's. You don't need to change payload type to Optional.